# Переменная let (область видимости)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Изучая переменные в js наткнулся на интересную вещь, а именно вот на такое

```
let a = 10;
(function(){
  console.log(a);
  let a = 100;
  console.log(a);
})();
```

Если это запустить через транскомпилятор то первая консоль выведет `undefined` и будет правильно т.к сработает всплытие переменной. Если этот код запустить без транскомпилятора то мы получим ошибку `Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined`

Вот тут и возникает вопрос, почему возникает ошибка без транскомпилятора ведь мы имеем доступ к переменной из вне? Объясните данную невнятность.

P.S Переменная var также как и функции всплывают, но всплывает ли переменная let? Разные источники пишут по-разному, "у кого-то всплывает, у кого-то нет"... не ясно... Так всплывает ли? И как работает всплытие переменной let?

Comment: Здесь хорошо все объясняется: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let . По сути let виден "внутри фигурных скобочек". Транспайлер типа babel, переводит let в var. Let и должен был решить "проблему" хойстинга.

Answer (score 0):

Второй раз переменная переопределяется внутри скобок, и интерпретатор проведя  анализ, знает что она будет определена внутри скобок, по этому не ищет ее во внешнем скопе, а выводит ошибку.
http://learn.javascript.ru/let-const
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вообще фраза: _до объявления их вообще нет_ не совсем корректна, они на самом деле есть

Comment: @Grundy ну это не моя фраза, а из учебника Ильи :)

Comment: Я знаю :-) на мой взгляд в нем довольно много проблем с формулировками и терминологией

Comment: Ну на мой взгляд, новичкам так понятней, а коль хочется глубже понять, то нужно самому копать

Comment: Учебник Ильи конечно один из лучших, но некоторые тонкие моменты не рассказываются, а жаль!